# How to get git to commit a "deleted by us" file?

Tags: git

I am attempting to merge and there are several files that are `deleted by us` under the `Unmerged paths:` heading.  It says to `use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution`.

It's strange, I thought that last time I had deleted by us objects, I used `mergetool` and it would ask if I want to delete it or take local, but `mergetool` doesn't work and it states `No files need merging`.  Other things I've tried are:

- Using `git add _filename_` results in the file being added to the stage area.  Not what I want.
- Using `git rm _filename_` results in `fatal: pathspec '_filename_' did not match any files.`
- If I add the file and then do a `git rm -f _filename_` it gets rid of the file, but is that how I should be doing this?

I feel that something has gone sideways in my local respository.  Can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `git rm` should suffice (though it complains a bit).  I set up a merge conflict for a file named `file`:

```
$ git merge sidebr
CONFLICT (modify/delete): file deleted in HEAD and modified
 in sidebr. Version sidebr of file left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        deleted by us:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git rm file
file: needs merge
rm 'file'
$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
```

If your situation is different, it would help if you provided more setup information and/or a transcript of an actual session, like the one above.

Comment: I'm not sure how I got the repo into the state that it is in now.  Doing a `rm _filename_` didn't work (still showed up in the status) until I tried to add it, and then it disappeared.  Kinda wonky.

Comment: @Adrian: If a plain (not `git`-prefixed) `rm` fails, the file doesn't exist in the work-tree. There may still be several staged copies in the index (in the higher stages, 1=base, 2=ours, 3=theirs). For a modify/delete conflict you'd have stages 1 and 2 with no stage 3 entry, by definition. `git rm` succeeds as long as the work-tree file exists: it removes the work-tree copy and the stage 1 and 2 copies. If the work-tree entry no longer exists, though, you can only `git rm --cached` or `git add` (which means "remove" since there's no work-tree version).